# C# - Updating Panel on UI from different DLL's

Tags: c#

I have a GUI that has behind it an interface that allows those dll's meeting it's contract to run through this GUI.  All the work and calculation is done within each dll.

I want to display an update as each record (within the dll) is processed, this update has to be on the GUI.

Is there a simple way of passing this information from the dll, as effectively they don't know what controls are on the GUI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function that lets the dll libraries inform your GUI when something changes.

For example you can have a delegate like this

```
delegate void NotifyChange(string action,string whatHasChanged);
```

Then you can change the methods in your libraries that accept a delegate:

```
void Porcess(....,NotifyChange notifyChange)
{
...

}
```

then you can call the callback function in your dll whenever you want to notify that something has changed:

```
...
if(notifyChange!=null)
notifyChange(thisAction,whatHappened);
...
```

and you can have an implementation for this delegate in your GUI to pass it to your methods.Instead of using a delegate you can use an interface.

Comment: Thanks, I take it this would need to be in the public interface part of the dll?  As my GUI knows nothing else apart from the public interface/contract?

Comment: this delegate or interface should be where both your libraries and GUI components can access it.It can be a public member of a common library